# Popup used to display on webpage, but no longer does

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I did have a popup on one of my webpages that used to display when I clicked a link but, while not knowing what's changed, It appears to have stopped displaying when I click the link. When using 'Inspect Element' using Chrome, the correct elements have the attribute 'display: block !important;' so should display.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function popup() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup")
    var popupLayer = document.getElementById("popup-layer")
    popup.classList.toggle("show")
    popupLayer.classList.toggle("show")
    }
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.click {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup {
    background-color: white;
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    align-self: center;
}
.popup-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
.popup-layer {
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}
#page-1 {
    background-color: #b3d9ff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-1">
    <div id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-wrapper">
        <div id="popup" class="popup center">
            <a class="click" onclick="popup()">Click me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="click" onclick="popup()">Click me!</a>
    <div id="popup-layer" class="popup-layer">

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a debugging question which is supposed to be done by you or at the least told us what you think it is.

Anyway, in `.popup-wrapper` I took out `height` as I presume it was spanning out of the view.

---

```js
function popup() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    var popupLayer = document.getElementById("popup-layer");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    popupLayer.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.click {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup {
    background-color: red;
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    align-self: center;
}
.popup-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
.popup-layer {
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}
#page-1 {
    background-color: #b3d9ff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-1">

    <div id="popup-wrapper" class="popup-wrapper">
        <div id="popup" class="popup center">
            <a class="click" onclick="popup()">Click me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="click" onclick="popup()">Click me!</a>
    <div id="popup-layer" class="popup-layer"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes thats popup-wrapper that is origin of the problem. But seing that you put your events in the a element its prefered to use this code to prevent the redirection or use button instead of this

```
var popupDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
var popupLayer = document.getElementById("popup-layer");
var clickMe=document.querySelectorAll(".click");
function popup() {
  popupDiv.classList.toggle("show");
  popupLayer.classList.toggle("show");
}
clickMe.forEach(function(elem){
  elem.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  popup()},false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS thus change this part

```css
.popup-wrapper {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

JS for the best way

```js
var popupDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
var popupLayer = document.getElementById("popup-layer");
var clickMe=document.querySelectorAll(".click");
function popup() {
  popupDiv.classList.toggle("show");
  popupLayer.classList.toggle("show");
}
clickMe.forEach(function(elem){
  elem.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  popup()},false);
});
```